# error with running simple spring application

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am following this tutorial to setup spring in my system, http://www.roseindia.net/spring/spring-mvc-hello-world.shtml.

Here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd" >
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>  
  <welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
  <bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
      <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
     <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
  </bean>
  <bean id="urlMapping"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
      <list>
        <ref local="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="urlMap">
      <map>
        <entry key="/hello.html">
          <ref bean="helloController"/>
        </entry>
      </map>
    </property>
  </bean>
  <bean id="helloController" class="net.roseindia.web.HelloWorldController"> </bean>
  <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="hl"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver"/>
</beans>
```

I am getting this error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - Servlet dispatcher is not available

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message Servlet dispatcher is not available

description The requested resource (Servlet dispatcher is not available) is not available.
```

What might be the problem? I have added the libraries through project build path and as well as in the lib folder of web-inf too.

Comment: I'd be very wary of anything I found on Rose India.  I don't think it's a good site to be learning from, as you've already found out.  Why don't you go to Spring's own site and study their stuff?  And use Spring 3 while you're at it; they're up to version 3.1 now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the webapp's logging level to DEBUG and look at the log messages produced by Spring as it wires up the webapp and dispatches the request.  This should give you some clues as to what is going wrong.

Can I also suggest that you use the official Spring manuals, tutorials and examples.  The stuff on Rose India looks like a recipe rather than a proper tutorial.  It doesn't explain what is going on.

Comment: well..I have installed it earlier too..but its the new system now and I am following the same steps but cant really understand what is going wrong... you gave a good suggestion of debugging..will try it now and let you know.

Comment: the debugger is showing me `this throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);` in URLClassLoader.class

Comment: @mad_programmer - in that case, this is a classpath issue of some kind.  See Aravind's answer.  If you've built the WAR file properly, all of the dependent JARs will be installed into the `WEB-INF/lib` directory when the web container unpacks the WAR file.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a class path issue . Can you check if the Spring-web jar is inside the WAR you have created . It's got to be inside web-inf lib . If you can find it there, open it up and check if the required DispatcherServlet file is inside that . If not, you have not added the dependencies properly .

Comment: I have added the libraries which were inside the spring dist folder though build path. And also copied all the jar files inside web-inf/lib too.

Comment: Have you checked the WAR created - If not, I suggest you open up the was and see if the lib file has gotten inside.